# WordPress Widgets using PHP or Shortcodes

Tags: php, shortcode, wordpress

I created a header area thats basically 6 widgets, 3 on 2 rows. However, I would like to place into one of the widgets some PHP or a shortcode. The widget will only read HTML as far as I know. Is there a way perhaps in the functions.php to allow shortcodes or PHP to be read and executed as well?

Comment: I would recommend using Exec-PHP plugin.  It allows you to create short-codes and execute php anywhere.  I use it and it works well.  See https://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable shortcode on text widget, just add filter in your theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Comment: That simple. Thanks, much appreciated.